# Não consigo acessar meu projeto Vue CLI pelo IP

Tags: javascript, linux, vue.js, servidor, webpack

Eu inicio meu projeto Vue CLI (template webpack) pelo terminal com `npm run dev` e inicializa tudo normal.
Consigo acessar meu projeto web pelo `localhost` ou `127.0.0.1`, mas quando tento acessar pelo ip da minha máquina não consigo, tanto pelo pc como pelo celular. 
Observações:

- Meu ip está certo pois peguei pelo `ifconfig`;
- Consigo dar ping no meu ip;
- A porta também está certa, pois consigo acessar pelo `localhost:8080`;
- Linux Ubuntu 18.04
- A rede está com internet;

Erro do celular e notebook: 
**Não é possível acessar esse site** 
**A conexão com 10.0.0.107 foi recusada.** 
[image: Erro do navegador do notebook]
[image: Retorno ifconfig e servidor rodando na porta 8080]

Comment: [RESOLVIDO] No projeto VueCli tem um arquivo de configuração em `config/index.js` na qual tem um atributo setado como `localhost` que é o atributo **host** ('module.exports'.dev.host). Assim você pode alterar o valor desse atributo para seu IP local e acessar pelo seu IP (Ex.: host: 'localhost' -> host: '192.168.0.85'). O problema dessa solução é que você não consegue mais acessar pelo `localhost`.